# document.cookie has not all cookies

Tags: asp.net, cookies

From XHR, I had one "Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH". It was really installed, as I saw that next XHR, had this cookie inside in request part. The strange is why document.cookie doesnot contain it?

Answer (score 1):

HttpOnly is the answer, looks like in this area we have an old war.

Comment: This is a security feature to protect cookie data against attacks like XSS.